# 'Where' query with condition for last association record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pg

I want get something like this:

```
Post.all.select{|p| p.comments.last.type == 'SpecialComment'}
```

I.e. I need select posts 'where' last comment has special type. How I can do it with active record query syntax?

Comment: What DB client you are using ? Postgresql/MySql/Oracle ?

Comment: it might be useful http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins and  http://habrahabr.ru/post/191762/

Comment: @shilovk spasibo, no che-to net

Comment: @GenaShumilkin and this http://rusrails.ru/active-record-query-interface#hash-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Post.joins(:comments).where("comments.last.type = ?", 'SpecialComment'")
```

Comment: `PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  schema "comments" does not exist`

Answer (score -2):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :comments
end

class SpecialComment < Comment
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, inverse_of: :comment, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :special_comments
end

Post.joins(:special_comments)
```

Comment: Can you explain your code. For me it seems like I am now going to learn something new here..

Comment: ok. It works for my example with field 'type'. But type is just example.

Comment: I gave an answer on the information you provided.. then I am told it works.. and then I am downvoted??  Ok..